# В чем разница между «вовсе не» и «совсем не»?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Делайте то, что от вас **вовсе не** ожидают.
>
> Делайте то, что от вас **совсем не** ожидают.

Интересно, чем по смыслу и употреблению один отличается от другого?

Comment: Здесь уместен средний род: одно отличается от другого.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, оба наречия **при отрицании** обозначают одно и то же, это полные синонимы.

Ушаков  значение одного слова выводит из другого: **Совсем (не)** - 2. **с отриц. Вовсе (не:)**. 
http://tolkslovar.ru/s8850.html

В словаре синонимов на Академике к слову **совсем** даются синонимы:• совершенно
• вовсе
• абсолютно
• отнюдь
• решительно
• положительно
• нисколько
• нимало
• ничуть
• ни чуточки
• ни капли
• ни капельки
• ни крошки
• ни крошечки
• ни на волос

**Вовсе не** тоже может использоваться в значении абсолютного отрицания, у того же Дмитриева есть пример такого употребления:

1. Слово вовсе используется при выражении уверенного отрицания чего-либо.
   Я вовсе не собирался вас обижать. | Он вовсе не бедный человек.
   **= абсолютно, совершенно, ни в коем случае**
2. Если вы отвечаете кому-то фразой Вовсе нет, значит, вы хотите **категорически** не согласиться с собеседником.

Попробуем их на взаимозаменяемость:

Вы вовсе не обязаны следовать совету = Вы совсем не обязаны следовать совету. Мне даже кажется, что в данном случае **вовсе не** передаёт отрицание  ярче, чем **совсем не.**

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, разница в том, что "слово *вовсе* используется при выражении **уверенного** отрицания чего либо" ([Толковый словарь Дмитриева](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=0)), в то время как *совсем нет* имеет смысл **абсолютного** отрицания (ни в какой степени, нисколько - [Толковый словарь Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=0)).

Comment: А в чем разница?

Comment: Мне кажется, что отрицание у наречий действительно РАЗНОЕ..  Я бы сказала, что у  СОВСЕМ НЕ отрицание полное (у вас оно названо абсолютным), если признак (действие) имеет градацию, например: они совсем не похожи (ни в какой степени, нисколько). У ВОВСЕ НЕ градации нет, это безотносительное отрицание, отрицание самого ФАКТА: они вовсе не похожи (если кто-то считает их похожими). У вас это уверенное отрицание, но я его бы  назвала абсолютным, или что-то вроде этого.  Но суть мне понятна.

Comment: @Jasmin Спасибо, с Вашими комментариями ситуация стала яснее.

Comment: Пожалуйста. И желаю Вам удачи. Вы здесь один из немногих, кто способен на нечто большее, чем поиск нужного правила. Вы - думающий.

Answer (score 2):

Наречия ***вовсе*** и ***совсем***, в том числе при наличии отрицания, **полными синонимами не являются.** Более того, они могут не являться синонимами вообще, то есть **не всегда заменяют друг друга**.

**Например:** (1) Ребенок еще **совсем маленький** (только *совсем*). (2) Или в диалоге: Ты тоже так считаешь? — **Вовсе нет** (только *вовсе нет*). (3) Мои родители были **вовсе не модные магнаты**, а физики и альпинисты... (только *вовсе не*).

Из словаря:

**СОВСЕМ,** нареч. 1. **Совершенно, полностью.** С. новая вещь. С. темно. На улице с. весна. С. готов. С. забыл. Он с. ещё мальчик. Не с. здоров. Не с. вас понимаю. Я как-то ему не с. доверяю. 2. **(перед отриц.). Разг.** Ни в какой степени, нисколько. С. не смешно.

**ВОВСЕ.** I. нареч. (обычно с отриц.). **Разг. Совсем, совершенно.** Мы думали, ты в. не придёшь. В. я этого не хочу. Не нужен он в. II. **частица**. Употр. для усиления отрицания. Ты боишься? — В. нет.

В словаре указаны **стилевые различия**. И действительно, когда слова заменяют друг друга, вариант ***вовсе*** кажется **разговорным**. В то же время у каждого слова есть и своя собственная область применения, что видно из приведенных примеров.

**Ответ на вопрос**

(1) Делайте то, что от вас вовсе не ожидают. (2) Делайте то, что от вас совсем не ожидают.

По смыслу замена возможна, поэтому **вариант (1) ближе к разговорной речи.**

Comment: *при наличии отрицания, полными синонимами не являются.* — Трудно поверить. Оттенки, конечно, могут быть, но очень тонкие, едва уловимые. В добротной литературе часто попадаются выражения, которые противоречат Вашим примерам: "совсем нет" в ответ на самые разные вопросы; конструкции типа "такой-то/такие-то совсем не трус/герой/ любое другое существительное"; многое другое.

Comment: Я привела три примера. Разве можно сказать: (1) Ребенок еще вовсе маленький. (2) Ты тоже так считаешь? — Совсем нет.  Странный ответ. Совсем - нет, а немного - да. (3) Мои родители были совсем не модные магнаты, а какие? - Просто магнаты, но не модные. Это по поводу трех приведенных примеров, а их может быть достаточно. ну вот еще пример: Вы устали? - Совсем немного. Неужели можно сказать "вовсе немного"? И по поводу разговорного стиля, отмеченного, кстати, в словаре. Тоже не согласны?

Comment: А ответ "вовсе нет" на на заданный вопрос имеет, как я думаю,  дополнительное значение (нет, конечно, напрасно вы так считаете).  Хотя я на своем мнении не настаиваю. Если лучшие люди форума  считают слова полными синонимами, наверное, так оно и есть (для них хотя бы).

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на что я возражаю. Это по поводу Ваших примеров с утверждениями. Что касается примеров с отрицаниями, а также разговорного стиля, посмотрите, пожалуйста, слово [совсем](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC&all=x) в словаре Кузнецова. Я не вижу никакой разницы, если мы говорим о наречиях. В примерах с частицей "вовсе" как в (2) есть небольшие оттенки, о которых я упомянул, но обратите внимание, что в этом случае не "вовсе" является разговорным, а только "совсем".

Comment: "Если лучшие люди форума..." — не нужно воспринимать настолько эмоционально. Я опираюсь на мнения лучших писателей страны, а также на словарные статьи. Ну и на лингвистов ещё (Апресян почему-то тоже не видел особой разницы).

Comment: А на свое мнение тоже опираетесь?  Меня интересовало, как лично вы относитесь к трем моим примерам, но вы на конкретный вопрос не отвечаете,  зато ссылаетесь на статьи и писателей. Я тоже просматривала Нацкорпус и отмечала там варианты, где замена возможна, а где нет.  Некоторые примеры у Кузнецова мне тоже кажутся странными, да и не все значения слов там обозначены.  Поэтому пусть все будут правы, взаимопонимание -  это так приятно. А меня вполне устраивает мое неправильное мнение (я говорю это совершенно искренне, нет никаких эмоций).

Comment: Если бы моё мнение не вступило в противоречие с Вашим, разве стал бы я искать подтверждения? Моё мнение: во всех примерах, которые я смог вспомнить/придумать, а также в приведенных Вами (с отрицаниями) являются полными синонимами, хотя в некоторых есть небольшие смысловые оттенки. Из Ваших объяснений по Вашим примерам я понял, что значение слова "совсем" при отрицании мы понимаем совершенно по-разному. Хорошо, не будем спорить.

Comment: Спорить, разумеется, не будем, да только ответа на заданный вопрос нет, хотя трое отвечали, вот что огорчительно.  Как мне кажется, между этими словами идет жесткая конкурентная борьба, наречие "вовсе" намерено сохраниться в языке, хотя еще  Ушаков отправил его к устаревшим, слова пытаются размежеваться и по стилю, и по значению. Но никто этого процесса не видит: ну вроде бы нет разницы, ну есть какие-то оттенки, ну одно ярче,  а другое бледнее. Разве это лингвистическая оценка? Скорее уж мнение пользователя, который над такими вопросами задумываться не привык.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Делайте то, что от вас вовсе не ожидают. (2) Делайте то, что от вас совсем не ожидают.**

Варианты различаются **по стилю, но не по смыслу.** Вариант ***вовсе не*** – разговорный.

Из Викисловаря: [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/вовсе](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5)

**ВОВСЕ**

с отрицанием, **разг**. совсем; также служит для **эмоционального** подчёркивания ◆ Он вовсе не жулик!

**разг.** полностью, окончательно ◆ Он стал писа́ть реже, а затем и вовсе пропал.

В словарях Дмитриева, Ушакова наречие ***вовсе*** отмечено как **разг., народн.** Так, в 18 веке частотность нейтрального (книжного) ***совсем***  значительно превышало частотность разговорно-народного ***вовсе***.

**Что касается семантики этих слов, то она часто совпадает, но может и отличаться.** Наречие ***совсем*** сочетается с прилагательными и глаголами, а наречие ***вовсе*** может относиться к прилагательным с приставкой НЕ (*совсем молодой, совсем/вовсе неплохой*).

**При сочетании с глаголами** также возможны различия.  Наречие ***совсем*** может иметь  значение "полностью", противопоставленное значению "частично", а у наречия ***вовсе*** нет такой градации. Например: Он то опоздает, то отпросится, а то и вовсе заболеет. Здесь указан сам факт, а вариант ***совсем*** заболеет может иметь значение "окончательно заболел".

Также при сочетании **с существительными есть различия**: *он вовсе не аристократ,  а простой человек; он совсем не аристократ* (в нем мало аристократического).

Таким образом, эти **наречия не являются полными синонимами.** Надо сказать, что полная синонимия обычно нехарактерна для языка (иметь два слова с одинаковым значением нерационально). Поэтому полные синонимы или меняют значение, или один из них уходит из языка.

В качестве примера можно привести наречие ***весьма***, которое сначала имело значение "совсем", а потом изменило его на "очень".